# Tutorial of the Chainhammer for TPS measurements of Quorum blockchain

Tags: quorum

Can anyone help me to found a detailed tutorial on how to use the Chainhammer for TPS measurements for the 7nodes example of the Quorum blockchain

I found this link https://gitlab.com/electronDLT/chainhammer/blob/master/quorum.md but I'm confused where I must run the listener (python tps.py) in the node or where..
 I need help please

Comment: Hi, probably easiest to catch Andreas on Quorum Slack. Heres the inviter: https://clh7rniov2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Express/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as running chainhammer. You run it on the same box / vagrant guest environment as quorum-examples. That means you clone quorum-examples first and get it running. Then clone chainhammer repo into the env, prime and start Quorum cluster through raft|istanbul-init or raft|istanbul-start and then run chainhammer stuff in other shell windows (tmux or whatever)